# Group data irrespective of its presence in the separate columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I have a table with different airline routes and I want to group them without taking into account which is the origin city and which is the destination.

e.g. the values of the routes Amsterdam-London and London-Amsterdam should be grouped together by the route Amsterdam-London.

Has anybody faced a similar problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you have table like

```
[flight routes]

originlocation| destinationlocation
 Amsterdam    | London
 London       | Amsterdam
```

You can try a set of sql queries like below

```
; with orderedroutes as
(
select distinct
   originlocation= Case when originlocation < destinationlocation  then originlocation else destinationlocation  end , 
   destinationlocation  = Case when originlocation < destinationlocation  then destinationlocation  else originlocation end 
from [flight routes]
)

select * from orderedroutes
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for

```
CREATE TABLE Routes(
  ID INT,
  OriginalLocation VARCHAR(45),
  Destination VARCHAR(45)
);

INSERT INTO Routes VALUES
(1, 'Amsterdam', 'London'),
(2, 'London', 'Amsterdam'),
(3, 'London', 'Algeria'),
(4, 'Algeria', 'France');

WITH C AS
(
  SELECT *,
         CASE WHEN EXISTS(
                          SELECT 1 
                          FROM Routes 
                          WHERE OriginalLocation = R.Destination --You can use UPPER()/LOWER() here
                                AND
                                Destination = R.OriginalLocation --and here too
                                AND
                                ID != R.ID
                         )
              THEN ID
              ELSE 0
         END G
  FROM Routes R
)
SELECT ID,
       OriginalLocation,
       Destination
FROM C
WHERE NOT (G > 1);
```

**Returns:**

```
+----+------------------+-------------+
| ID | OriginalLocation | Destination |
+----+------------------+-------------+
|  1 | Amsterdam        | London      |
|  3 | London           | Algeria     |
|  4 | Algeria          | France      |
+----+------------------+-------------+
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=349bd87a5cd1c187f8da5a06c820afcb)**